# Как в laravel сохраненные файлы привязать к модели

Tags: laravel

Имеется общая Eloquent Модель "File" предназначенная для работы с файлами. На нее будут ссылаться модели User, Post, Video и прочее тому подобное.

Схема таблицы "files":

```
Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('bytes');
    $table->string('mime_type');
    $table->string('disk');
    $table->string('path')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

При создании поста(модель Post) в форме с названием, описанием и другими полями, также можно загрузит файлы, например картинки. Форма устроена таким образом, что как только я выбираю файлы в input file, они сразу же загружаются на сервер. Там создается новый экземпляр File, файл сохраняется на сервер, информация о нем пишется в базу и все это возвращается в форму, где клиент продолжает вводить оставшиеся данные.

```
<input type="file"
    v-on:change.prevent="upload($event.target.files)"
    multiple
/>

<script>

    upload(files) {

        let formData = new FormData();

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            formData.append('files[]', files[i]);
        }

        axios.post('/file/upload', formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
            .then(response => console.log(response.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

</script>
```

Прошу обратить внимание что новый экземпляр File не привязан каким-либо способом к другим моделям и может создаваться вне зависимости от других моделей.

После того как пользователь ввел оставшиеся данные и отправил на сервер, включая информацию о сохраненных файлах(id и все такое), данные пройдя валидацию инициализируют создание экземпляра Post и соответственно записывает их в базу. Здесь как-то нужно "прикрепить" ранее загруженные файлы к создаваемому посту, мы ведь уже имеем информацию о них.

То есть модель File может и должна существовать как некая обособленная единица, а так же как некий attachment для других моделей. Так что бы в конечном итоге я мог делать следующее:

```
$post = App\Post::with('files')->find(1);
dd($post->files);
```

или

```
$user = App\User::with('files')->find(1);
dd($user->files);
```

В обоих случаях $post->files и $user->files должны ссылаться на одну и ту же модель - File

Я пробовал использовать полиморфные связи но они подразумевают, что при сохранении файла уже имеется сохраненная модель Post. В моем же случае все проходит наоборот: сначала сохраняется файл(ы), потом пост, что приводит к следующей ошибке:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'fileable_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `files` (`mime_type`, `bytes`, `disk`, `path`, `client_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (image/png, 976, upload, 1jXnHtcBh3pWCQTsXMQ7Ax4OkapCn9XqyLVD2CWT.png, favicon.png, 2020-03-30 11:09:21, 2020-03-30 11:09:21))
```

Понимаю что могу что-нибудь "накостылить", но хотелось бы знать "best practics" на такие случаи, или возможно вы сталкивались с подобными задачами и как из них выходили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Невозможность сохранения файла без привязки его к модели поста, пользователя и т.д. решил внесением в миграции таблицы files вместо

```
$table->morphs('fileable');
```

указал

```
$table->string('fileable_type')->nullable();
$table->bigInteger('fileable_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно почему у Вас возникли проблемы с этим.

После сохранения файлов Вы отправляете на фронт объекты сохранённых файлов или их id. 
Далее отправляете заполненную инфу к примеру:

```
const info = {
    title: 'news 1',
    body: 'text',
    attached: [
       //тут указываете id вернувшихся изображений
       1,
       2
    ]
}

//ajax...
```

Далее в контроллере:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->title;
....
$post->save();
//далее должна быть связь многие ко многим
$post->files()->attach($request->attached);
return response()->json($post);
```

Ну и потом, в других местах можете вызывать как хотите в том числе как указали выше.

**P.S** в качестве домашнего задания, что будете делать если пользователь на фронте обновит страницу или прекратит создавать новость после сохранения изображений в вашу файловую систему? через некоторое время всё заполонит не нужными файлами).